# I want to change address to coordinate to show on a google map

Tags: google-maps

I have more than 600 address on my site and I would like to show them all on the same map. For that I have to get the coordinate. Is there a site somewhere where I upload enter my 600 address and get 600 coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a FusionTable(possible via [file-upload](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/181717?hl=en), e.g. CSV) and display the addresses via a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer)

It will take some time until all the rows  have been geocoded, but as long as the expected amount of addresses (600) doesn't exceed the daily limit(2500) it shouldn't take too long(let's assume 1 address/sec)